# unable to update NaturalId field value: An immutable natural identifier of entity {Model} was altered from ABC to XYZ

Tags: java, spring-boot

Using spring-boot with JPA:
trying to do Update table. but getting error when i update NaturalId field value.

`ERROR:nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: An immutable natural identifier of entity com.model.Company was altered from SOL to MEP`

Model Entity:

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "COMPANY_ID")
  private Long companyId;

  @NotBlank
  @NaturalId
  @Size(max = 5)
  @Column(name = "COMPANY_CODE")
  private String companyCode;
```

Controller & Service :

```
@PutMapping("/company")
public ResponseEntity<?> updateCompany(@Valid @RequestBody CompanyRequest companyRequest) {
    logger.info("UPDATE COMPANY :  {} ", companyRequest);

    Company company = companyService.updateCompany1(companyRequest);

    URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
                .fromCurrentRequest().path("/{companyId}")
                .buildAndExpand(company.getCompanyId()).toUri();

    return ResponseEntity.created(location)
                .body(new ApiResponse(true, "Company Updated Successfully"));
}

//Services:
public Company updateCompany1(CompanyRequest companyRequest) {
        Company company = companyRepository.findById(companyRequest.getCompanyId())
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Company", "companyId", companyRequest.getCompanyId()));
        company.setCompanyCode(companyRequest.getCompanyCode());
        return companyRepository.saveAndFlush(company);
}
```

Comment: A natural id is an immutable identifier that makes sense in the context of your domain. A typical example is the ISBN for books or IBAN for bank accounts. They do not change, hence the exception when you try to do that.

Comment: You can - however - make it mutable: `@NaturalId(mutable = true)`.

Comment: Thanks. now i can able to update NaturalId field value after using mutable-true.
but, this field should not be duplicate. i can create new record with same value. how to stop creating duplicate....??? thanks again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) set the mutable attribute on the NaturalId and 2) make your Column unique:

Your mapping should look like:

```
@NotBlank
@NaturalId(mutable=true)
@Size(max = 5)
@Column(name = "COMPANY_CODE", unique=true)
private String companyCode;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works so fine.... but why i need to remove table and build again... if i do any structure change in model class...? like unique = true

Comment: Unique generates a unique key constraint on the database

Comment: Rebuilding the table was not required in my case: I already had the `@NaturalId` and the `unique` constraints, only `mutable = true` was added.